# SQL Server: How to concatenate string constant with date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

```
select packageid,status+' Date : '+UpdatedOn from [Shipment_Package]
```

The below error is appeared when executing the above code in sql server. The type of `UpdatedOn` is `DateTime` and status is a `varchar`. We wanted to concatenate the status, Date and UpdatedOn.

error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Comment: is there at least one word null in the text of the question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to convert `UpdatedOn` to `varchar` something like this:

```
select packageid, status + ' Date : ' + CAST(UpdatedOn AS VARCHAR(10))
from [Shipment_Package];
```

You might also need to use [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) if you want to format the datetime in a specific format.

Answer (score 1):

To achive what you need, you would need to CAST the Date?

Example would be;

Your current, incorrect code:

```
select packageid,status+' Date : '+UpdatedOn from [Shipment_Package]
```

Suggested solution:

```
select packageid,status + ' Date : ' + CAST(UpdatedOn AS VARCHAR(20))
from [Shipment_Package]
```

[MSDN article for CAST / CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To account for null values, try this:

```
select packageid, 
    'Status: ' + isnull(status, '(null)') + ', Date : ' 
    + case when UpdatedOn is null then '(null)' else convert(varchar(20), UpdatedOn, 104) end as status_text
from [Shipment_Package]
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert Datetime column into varchar  for sql Server you can use below code

```
select packageid,status+' Date : '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,UpdatedOn,120) from [Shipment_Package]
```

120 code will convert your date into this format : 2020-06-12 15:09:00
other format you can use from [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)